# Where to call action methods

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Well, for example I have container and api:

container:

```
...

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleSubmitForm: (signin_data) => {
    dispatch(getUserInfo(signin_data))
  }
})

...
```

api:

```
...

export function logIn( data ){
  return  dispatch => {
    dispatch(startFetching('signin'))
    return axios.post(domain + '/signin', {user: data})
      .then(response => {
        setTokensToLocalStorage( response.data )
        dispatch(fetchingSuccess('signin'))
        dispatch(getCurrentUser())
        hashHistory.push('/')
        dispatch(callFlash('success', 'signIn'))})
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(fetchingFailed('signin'))
        dispatch(callFlash('error', 'signInFail'))})
}}

/some simple functions for logout, signup etc/
...
```

It seems, that it should be like that:

```
...

export function logIn( data ){
  return  dispatch => {
    dispatch(startFetching('signin'))
    return axios.post(domain + '/signin', {user: data})
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(fetchingSuccess('signin'))})
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(fetchingFailed('signin'))})
}}

/some simple functions for logout, signup etc/
...
```

But in which place should I call other methods? May be in container, but it will be strange to import this methods in every container, when I can import them just once in api

```
dispatch(getCurrentUser())
hashHistory.push('/')
dispatch(callFlash('success', 'signIn'))
dispatch(callFlash('error', 'signInFail'))
```

Comment: how about in componentDidMount?

Comment: @Winter Well, then they will be called every time i redirect to '/', but i need them only when logging in

Comment: and you can't wrap them in an if-statement checking if the user is signed in from state?